# HIbernate auto delete old data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4 to manage all the databases connection.
In the table i'm creating i'd like to keep only the last 24 hour data for statistic calculation.
Is there a way to automatic delete older data on the table (obvius there's a field EVENTDATA of type DATETIME) or i've to do this manually every x minute?

Comment: Second option is the best (if not only one). Just schedule your delete agent and thats it.

Comment: I wouldn't do that every X minutes though; it should be enough to do it once every day at an opportune time when the load on the database will be low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  job scheduling with cron trigger to achive this. if you use cron expression **0 0 0 * *** then the delete trigger will invoke for every night at 00:00

Comment: If you are using spring, it will be very easy. because of spring provide those functionalities in build on